# Parse JSON attribute "data" using gson and retrofit2 in fancy way

Tags: android, gson, retrofit2

Well, I've seen alot of boilerplate code in my model classes when I need to parse json using GSON with Retrofit2. I would like to find out how to deal with it, because I'm pretty sure there is a way to make this look more elegant.

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 2,
      "price": 56,
      "name": "Hello"
    }
  ]
}
```

For parsing this json I would need to create 2 model classes. One would be for the inner object (id, price, name) and one would be Data.class which holds one attribute - List of this inner object.

It's totally okay to have different inner objects inside, but later on you will have many "Data.class" which has one attribute "data" which is List, but with different inner object type. How can I avoid this boiler-plate Data lookalike classes in my projects?

**What I want:**

Is to NOT create new Data class with "data" attribute changing inner object type whenever I create new "inner" object model class.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and fix that with create one abstract class with name BaseResponse like this

```
public abstract class BaseResponseInterface2<T> {

    @SerializedName("data")
    private List<T> data;

    public List<T> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(List<T> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

And use that like this in api service interface

```
@GET("/api/")
Call<BaseResponseInterface2<innerClass>> getResponse(
        @Path("id") int id
);
```

Hope it help